# How to get google sheet multiple tabs data as JSON?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can you some help to get google sheets multiple tabs data as single JSON ?

Comment: Have you got a single tab? How are you doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use the Sheets API to get the data of each sheet pre-compiled as a JSON.*

#### More Information:

The [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) endpoint of the Google Sheets API allows you to get the data from a Spreadsheet by specifying the Spreadsheet ID. The URL for the endpoint is:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET-ID
```

You can use a [field mask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask) to narrow down the data in the response you get from the API. In order to only get the Sheet name and the data, you can use:

```
sheets(properties/title,data/rowData/values/userEnteredValue)
```

to test using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22yourSpreadsheetId%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22sheets(properties%2Ftitle%2Cdata%2FrowData%2Fvalues%2FuserEnteredValue)%22%7D), or if using the URL directly:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/yourSpreadsheetId?fields=sheets(properties/title,data/rowData/values/userEnteredValue)
```

#### Example Response:

```json
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "title": "Sheet1"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 12
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {},
                {},
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 123
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Working with field masks | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/field-masks)
- [Package google.protobuf | Protocol Buffers | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf)

  - [google.protobuf.FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask)

Comment: For filed mask it's probably better to use formattedValue :: `sheets(properties/title,data/rowData/values/formattedValue)`